# .getJSON IE issue - .ajax solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, getjson

First time asking anything. Be gentile. =)

I've been put in the position to fix someone else's code. I barely have any js experience, but I'm the only one available to try.

Only thing I know is that this works in FF and Chrome. IE8,9 give absolutely nothing.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {

    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "http://goodlordineedhelp.com/api/v1/getSubCategoryDetailsTest?id=<?php echo $category_details->subcategory_info->subcategory_id; ?>",
    "sAjaxDataProp": "aaData",
    "aoColumns": [
    null,
    { "bSortable": false },
    { "bSortable": false },
    { "bSortable": false }
],
    "fnServerData": function ( sAjaxSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {

        $.getJSON( sAjaxSource, aoData, function (json) { 
            $.each(json.aaData, function(index,val) {
                val[0] = '<a href="/index.php/tools/api-lee?function=forward&val='+val[4]+'">'+val[0]+'</a>';
            fnCallback(json);
            });
        });
    }
```

I did some research and think I've isolated it to an issue with .getJSON based on several similar issues I found. With my limited knowledge, I put together the following, but was unable to get it to work.

```
$.ajax({
cache: "false",
type: "get",
url: sAjaxSource,
data: aoData,
    dataType: "jsonp",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
success: function (result) { 
    $.each(result.aaData, function(index,val) {
        val[0] = '<a href="/index.php/tools/api-lee?function=forward&val='+val[4]+'">'+val[0]+'</a>';
    fnCallback(result);
    }); 
}
});
```

I am eternally grateful for any help.

Comment: What does not work, what is the error?

Comment: is `http://goodlordineedhelp.com` the same address you are using to get to the page? (obviously i mean what it was originally before you changed it in the question). Simply changing the request to jsonp isn't going to do any good if the api doesn't support jsonp.

Comment: In IE, press `F12`, open the console, and reload the page, then cause the ajax request. Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: @Kevin

The table headers appear, but none of the data shows up. I get absolutely no errors in the console.

The sAjaxSource url is a different address than the one I'm using to get to the page. That's what led me to believe that .getJSON was the problem - hence my terrible .ajax attempt.

Thanks!

Comment: If you perform the same test, but having the network tab open, do you see the request? does anything about the request look odd?

Comment: @KevinB

I do not see the request. I only see a css import before and image requests after, which make sense in the bigger picture.

Comment: Not really, you should either see the request or an error. Seeing nothing doesn't really make sense, unless something is stopping the code from even reaching $.getJSON.

Comment: I see the successful request using firebug. Absolutely nothing in IE.